# A Block blob file is getting generated for each new folder when doing copy activity

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

Trying to copy a folder (JSON data) to another ADLS container using Azure data lake storage Gen2. But a file with same name is auto generated along with new folders created. Kindly help on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkhG6.png)

Source
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKrA1.png)

Sink
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHmqd.png)

Dataset-source
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N94wF.png)

Dataset-sink
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svGBv.png)

Comment: Could you please add the picture of your copy activity source and sink confugurations?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @RakeshGovindula. I have attached those details. Please let me know if you need any other details.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this with the below JSON files in a test folder but getting proper results with same configurations as above.

[image]

**Sink in Copy activity:**

[image]

**Target JSON dataset:**

[image]

**Sink in copy activity:**

[image]

**Target files after Execution:**

[image]

You can see the **test** Folder with **JSON** files were copied successfully.

I have encountered the similar issues where extra file is created sometimes when working on dataflows and databricks. The extra file won't create any problem for you as your folder is copied successfully. You can ignore that file or delete it.

If you didn't resolve with copy behavior as **Preserve hierarchy**, you can try and check with other options here.

[image]

I have checked all the above options and apart from Merge files, all will give you the same result.